# Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I'm creating a very basic SpringBoot application with Netflix Zuul proxy. I'm getting this error during startup. I followed another StackOverflow thread about a similar error and I realized that there's a compatibility issue between spring web and spring cloud dependencies. I'd appreciate if someone can tell what should be the matching versions for this pom file?

- `spring-boot-maven-plugin` - 2.3.4.RELEASE
- `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul` - 2.2.9.RELEASE
- `spring-boot-starter-test` - 2.5.4
- `spring-boot-starter-web` - 2.5.4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>HospitalGatewayService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>HospitalGatewayService</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: zuul is not compatible with boot 2.4-2.5, only 2.3

Answer (score 2):

Please note that Zuul has been replaced by Spring Cloud Gateway so if you want to keep with the current spring-boot version `2.5.4` you will have to switch to the Gateway project instead.

A `pom.xml` generated by Spring Initializr (https://start.spring.io/) with selecting dependencies "Spring Web" and "Gateway", for spring-boot version `2.5.4` is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I often do, whenever Im working with spring I use spring dependency management to decide version instead of manually enter the version.

The plugin will control the versions of your project’s dependencies and will honour any exclusions declared in the poms of your project’s dependencies.

It also let you override if needed.

- Maven follow - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency-management-custom-parent
- Gradle - https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html